# How to filter an ItemGroup if the items not exist in another ItemGroup

Tags: msbuild

I have a ItemGroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MainItem Include="A;B;C;D;E;F" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I would like to filter from another ItemGroup if the items not exist in the above ItemGroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <MyItem Include="A;C;G;H" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
   <Filtered Include="@(MyItem)" Condition="If %(MyItem.Identity) not exists in @(MainItem)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I expect `@(Filtered) = 'G;H'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly there is a way to do this using batching as you tried, but I didn't find it immediately and even if it's possible it won't be as simple and elegant as this one:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Filtered Include="@(MyItem)" Exclude="@(MainItem)" />
</ItemGroup>
```